# Catching the error and continue back to the calling function

Tags: c++, c, regex, flex-lexer, lex

I am building a scanner/lexical_analyser using decaf language in flex/lex tool.

To check for identifiers I implemented regular expression `id [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*`

```
{id} { matchedID(); return T_Identifier; }
```

I also like to check for bad identifiers so I wrote a method to handle it:

```
    * Checking ID validness */
static void matchedID()
{
  strncpy(yylval.identifier,yytext,MaxIdentLen);
  if (yyleng > MaxIdentLen)
  {
    ReportError::LongIdentifier(&yylloc,yytext);
    return;
  }
}
```

Now when I run my scanner over a test_file that contains:

`vari.able`,
`3variable`,
`variable/123`,
`var-123`,
`variable_whose_name_is_much_too_long`

the scanner escapes checking all variables and reports error about last long variable (decaf var max_size_is 31 so it truncates it accordingly).
If I take out the variable with long name, the scanner scans the rest of file perfectly!
Can anyone tell me how to fix it so when scanner finds a long variable and reports error, it should also scan other statement in the file ?

Comment: @ctwheels thanks for the suggestion, but my main problem is that the program doesn't read the whole file after it finds a error !

Comment: Nothing in this code appears to abort the scan. The answer seems to depend on the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: @Beta although my problem has been solved now, but let me update the question with the part that is missing :)

Comment: @rici thanks, wasn’t aware of that. I’ll remove my comment to prevent further confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I noticed that somehow the scanner script was not syncing with my server and the changes I made were local to client side only, as soon as the server started synchronizing with client files everything started working back a like a charm.

I wanted to delete my question, but then I thought someone else might face the same problem in the future :)